# Maven dependencies sharing class loader

Tags: java, maven, classloader, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a 3 maven projects with different groupIds/ArtifactIDs. Project A has depedencies on projects B and C. and I'm using [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) in order to run B's and C's integration tests from A during build:

(In project A) :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.b</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactB</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactC</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But for some reason, when I run this line in Project C -

```
URL path = ThisClass.class.getResource("/someResource");
```

It gives me the jar location of Project B, as in the classloader is in projectB

Both B and C have a resource directory called `/someResource` and thats why its failing. When I do the same call but to a resource that exists ONLY in C, then the class loader is correct:

(Code written in Project C)

```
    URL path1 = SomeClass.class.getResource("/directory1");
    System.out.println(pathA.getPath()); // .m2/../ProjectB.jar!/directory1

    URL path2 = SomeClass.class.getResource("/directory2");
    System.out.println(pathB.getPath()); // .m2/../ProjectC.jar!/directory2
```

Since directory1 exists in B and C, then A gives me B's class loader (the first depedency), and when its a directory that exists only in C, *then* I get the correct class loader

If I comment out the dependency to B, then all works good.

I've also added `<useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>` to maven-failsafe and that didn't help

I've also tried `<useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>` which didn't change anything

## ======UPDATE=======

If anyone has a suggestion as to how I can run test jars externally (jenkins, maven, doesn't matter) without having their class loader mixed up

Comment: "and I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin in order to run B's and C's integration tests from A during build" -> OMG

Comment: @davidhxxx meaning what? is that not possible? even when I run only C's tests, it still points to B's classloader

Comment: I don't know if it is possible. But your error seems not surprising seeing the way you use Maven.  Each projets should run its own integration tests and not which of others projects.

Comment: I'm interested in finding a way to run all of the integration tests in one place. Each of these projects has an integration-test.jar which I should be able to run in one place, one after the other

Comment: But why ? Why not letting each project running its integration tests ?Integration tests are located in a project because it has a meaning. If it is not the case and you think that all tests must be executed from the same project, why don't you move all your integration tests in a dedicated project which runs all its **integration tests**?

Comment: We have a multi-module project, and projects interact with eachother, I don't want Project B to deliver its code without having run Project C's integration tests together with B's candidate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121223/discussion-between-orepor-and-davidhxxx).

Comment: i need the same behaviour to test some classes from lib in one project instead of exploding the test on several projects. And just to find how to add dependencies jar class in current classpath because we need it